# d3.js Transition on div not working

Tags: d3.js, transition

I try to change a divs html by a transition, but dont get it running. Can anybody point me to my mistake please:

Working fine:

```
d3.select("#tt").html(d.name+"<BR>"+d.group);
```

Not working:

```
d3.select("#tt").transition().html(d.name+"<BR>"+d.group);
```

Comment: are you trying to transition the text?

Comment: yes. No text -> Transition -> Text.

Comment: So after transition you want to display the text aaah..??

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.select("#tt").transition().html(d.name+"<BR>"+d.group);
```

instead of above html function try with text() function.
If it is also not working, develop fiddle then we could do something.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I would like to withdraw my question :). It makes no real sense to apply a transition on html/test setting. My solution is to set the text without a transition, set the opacity to 0 and then apply a transition to fade it in.

Comment: Okay.
Well, that's your choice.